# Grep command to skip commented lines

Tags: linux

I trying to grep for a pattern in a file. I want skip the pattern occurrence if it is commented in that file.
For example, there are 2 occurrence of that pattern, but output should be 1 occurrence. Basically it should skip commented lines
Can you please  suggest a way for this

Comment: There are plenty of kind of comments - `/*  */` or `<!-- -->` or `#` or `//` ... Perhaps you can specify what comments you want to filter out.

Comment: I am performing this grep in .pl file. I am using # and =head..=cut for commenting

Answer (score 6):

A simple, common way to strip shell comments is:

```
egrep -v '^\s*#' <file>
```

Here, `egrep` is `grep` with a regular expression pattern as input. The pattern '^\s#' describes lines starting with a '#' letter, or with any amount of whitespace followed by '#'. The option `-v` inverts the match (non-matching lines get through). You can then pipe to your further pattern search.

**Caveat:** Comments that appear after code (e.g. `echo 'foo' # bar`) will not get stripped. You cannot do that with this piping solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the option -F in grep. -F stands for fixed strings. For example I have a file that has the below data :

```
System out of memory
#System out of memory 
System out of memory #1  
1 #System out of memory
```

Now grep with the -F

```
 grep -rF "#System out of memory" <path to grep>
```

Output

```
./file1:#System out of memory
./file1:1 #System out of memory
```

This is the basic ideology. Based on your pattern, it has to be modified

Comment: I tried same but if search only for System out of memory, it is will not skip the commented lines..right? 

`>grep -rF "System out of memory" 1.pl
System out of memory
#System out of memory
System out of memory #1
1 #System out of memory`

Answer (score 1):

when using `grep -r` you have to use `grep -Ev [.\:]#` .

When using grep recursive, you must remember that the output will be with filename and colon:

```
user@hostname [/root]:# grep -r matching /location/
/location/filename:#1st commented line matching
/location/filename:#2nd commented line matching
/location/filename:matching without comment
/location/filename:other line with matching #and comment
/location/filename:other line #matching after comment
/location/filename:#3rd commented line matching
/location/filename:#4th commented line matching
```

so, to filter out comments `| grep -v ^#` simply won't work, since every line is started with filename. Using `grep -v '.*#'` would remove any line with comment and it would be to much.

You have to do `grep -Ev [.\:]#`, which will work well resaulting:

```
user@hostname [/root]:# grep -r matching /location/ | grep -Ev [.\:]#
/location/filename:matching without comment
/location/filename:other line with matching #and comment
/location/filename:other line #matching after comment
```

Works well with subdirectories and filenames with spaces or anything :)